# How to make Google Chrome show certain file extensions as text in the browser or at least in a text editor?

Tags: google-chrome

I mainly use Google Chrome these days under Ubuntu (18.04) with the MATE desktop manager, but there is one thing I could not figure out yet:

If there is a link on a web site that points to e.g. a "bib" file, i.e. a BibTeX file with extension ".bib" Chrome wants to download it. 
All bib-files are really text files so I would want chrome to just show the text of the file in a browser window like it would for a text file (with extension .txt). 
The second best option would be if I could make Chrome to open the file in e.g. gedit based on its extension.

With Firefox it is possible to configure this directly in the browser, but Chrome delegates this, I think, to the OS, so how make sure it works in Ubuntu (at least the second-best option)?

Does this require different solutions depending on the desktop used (Unity, XFCE, MATE)?

UPDATE: most problematic links are those where the link is not a static link to a file with .bib extension, but some link to a script or a javascript link. Ultimately the save as dialog that pops up shows a filename with a .bib extension, but it may be that what is sent back has an odd mime type. So I guess what I would need is that the .bib extension of what gets sent back overrides any mime type and gets handled as plain text.

Comment: That is a cool suggestion, but it turns out that those cases where I keep having those problems are ones, where I do not get a URL from the browser window: I click a link which programmatically makes some URL get sent, so the URL I click is not what I get (the link I click may also be some javascript). This is done frequently by publishers on their pages, sadly.

Comment: That's generally controlled not by the file extension, but by [the content type HTTP header, which tells what type of file it is, being handlable by the browser and the content disposition HTTP header, which tells whether the browser should display it if it can or if it should be downloaded (for example, the server can cause a text document or a PNG image to either be displayed or downloaded)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509354/7208029). You may be able to find a Chrome extension that does this with file extensions.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I would not mind defining this based on the mime type, thought I think the extension would still be important in many cases as the servers seem to send rubbish mime types often. I just observe that in Firefox, it is no problem to do this, in Google Chrome it appears to be impossible.